# Images on Woocommerce shop are smashed and distorzed?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

i have one CSS issue (i hope so). After inserting this CSS by my side:

```
.owl-item>.product .product-thumbnail>img, .owl-item>.product .wp-post- 
image, .products:not(.electro-v1)>.product .product-thumbnail>img, 
.products:not(.electro-v1)>.product .wp-post-image {
height: 320px !important;
}
```

images on [shop](https://marketplace.blissfullight.com) are alligned properly, but this caused some images to be scretched or distorzed, its not in their natural size.. Can someone to tell me where is my error in my CSS, and what to do to fix it? Many thanks

Comment: What type of element is `.wp-post-image` ? It would help if you included the relevant html

Comment: For example

`<img width="300" height="300" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/518dfyMchQL.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">`

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you're stretching the image by forcing the height to be 320px. Try applying the height to the wrapper element instead:

```
.owl-item>.product .product-thumbnail, 
.products:not(.electro-v1)>.product .product-thumbnail {
  height: 320px !important;
}
```

Comment: This makes images not equal in height.

Comment: Correct. Since your images aren't equal in height/aspect-ratio to begin with that's the only way not to stretch them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in functions.php of your theme.

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );

function remove_thumbnail_dimensions( $html ) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
    return $html;
}
```